# Cakephp pdf image conversion issue

Tags: cakephp

How to put this :

```
 WWW_ROOT."images".DS."uploaded_files".DS."research".DS. $pdfname;
```

inside this

```
  exec("convert -scale  1500x1000 " . escapeshellarg(BASE_URL."app/webroot/images/uploaded_files/research/${dirname}/img%d_".$pdfname.".png"));
```

replacing **BASE_URL."app/webroot/images/uploaded_files/research/${dirname}/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with this:

```
$path = WWW_ROOT."images".DS."uploaded_files".DS."research".DS. $pdfname.".png";
exec("convert -scale  1500x1000 " . escapeshellarg($path));
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried this but png image of pdf is not formed.Suppose my pdf is abc.pdf instead abc is formed instead of abc.png

Comment: That shouldn't be possible - the `".png"` at the end of the string should mean it always has `.png` at the end. Unless I misunderstand? If you want to give an actual example of something you've tried I might understand more and can try to help.